# Use an iPhone AppID more than once?

Tags: iphone

I am wondering if I can use the same AppID for multiple games. Or do I have to create a new one for every game? (com.example.example). Please let me know. Thanks

-michael

Answer (score 0):

You need a unique app ID for each app.